# C#, take off +00:00 in DateTime Object

Tags: c#, datetime

So i need a date time object formated to something like "2018-01-19T09:06:46.175Z", i do this by useing the code to set the string format then parse back into a datetime object

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
ReqMsg.Request.HeaderNode.MsgDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

with this i get back something like "2018-01-19T09:07:09.736+00:00" is there anyway to put it to something like  "2018-01-19T09:06:46.175Z" without the "+00:00"
Cheers

Comment: `ReqMsg.Request.HeaderNode.MsgDateTime` is a DateTime - why not just set it to `DateTime.Now` ? The Z is the timezone and you are not supplying any so it displays +00:00

Comment: i should also mention i am using a soap web service which requests that i have the object as a "system.dateTime"

Comment: the server asks for the time to be displayed like "2018-01-19T09:06:46.175Z" with a z at the end but no +00:00

Comment: `ReqMsg.Request.HeaderNode.MsgDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow` => this should you're looking for.

Comment: The point of @PatrickArtner's comment is that the value in `MsgDateTime` has _no_ format. Saying you want it _"without the +00:00 at the end"_ makes no sense. The `DateTime` value is a `DateTime` value, not a `string` value. Only a `string` value could have anything "at the end".

Comment: right i see what your saying, so theres no chance of removing it?, as this datetime object gets put into an xml file through a proxy class then gets sent to the soap server, but the soap server dosent like the +00:00

Comment: A `DateTime` is, internally, just a count of the number of 100ns intervals since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001, plus a couple of bits to encode the `Kind` property. If you want to change what happens when it's converted into a *string*, you need to *locate the code that's turning it into a string and change that code*. No amount of futzing around with the value whilst it remains a `DateTime` will change what happens later when it's turned into a string.